# SQL server Active Directory permissions over-riding user permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, windows

I have an SQL server on which my User has db_owner privilages.

I also have an Active Directory group which I am a member of.

It appears that my membership of the active directory group is over-riding my specific user permissions for example. I ran this command:

```
DENY SELECT ON table_name to "DOMAIN\AD_GROUP"
```

This worked, but I can no longer view the table from my own db_owner user.

I can reverse this with

```
GRANT SELECT ON table_name to "DOMAIN\AD_GROUP"
```

But I want to be able to allow the select privilages to myself, despite my own user being part of this active directory, since the AD gives access to a lot of other things also.

Comment: It's not "overriding" it, permissions are cumulative and you have both the `DENY` and `GRANT` permission. As `DENY` permissions have a higher priority than `GRANT` you are denied the permission. You either need to *not* be part of that group or the group should not have the `DENY` permission.

Comment: Hey again @Larnu, thanks for this (and your comprehensive answer on my other question). I think I've worked out a solution which is use REVOKE instead of DENY, but haven't had a chance to go on a different account to test it.